# Run import.sql only on create/create-drop

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot with Hibernate. I have data.sql in resources and it runs everytime I start the application. Is that possible to set it to run only when

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

is set on create/create-drop?
Thanks for answer.